# A probability question about Bayes rule

Tags: probability

There is a probability related question as follows:

"On certain exams, Bob will be given a multiple-choice question with *n* choices, only one of which is correct. There is a probability of *p* that Bob has already seen the question, in which case he knows the solution. But if Bob hasn't seen the question, he chooses one of the choices at random uniformly. What is the probability that he saw the question, given that Bob responded correctly?"

Following is what I have done so far which is not complete/correct,

If *S* is seeing the question and *K* is knowing the solution then:

$P(S|K) = \frac{P(S,K)}{P(K)} = \frac{p+\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}} = (P\times n) + 1$

The answer is greater than 1, how to fix it?

Comment: That answer appears to be greater than $1$.

Comment: @Lulu You are correct, I edit.

Comment: I can't follow any part of your calculation.  Why do you think $P(K)=\frac 1n$?  Why do you think that $P(S\cap K)=p+\frac 1n$?

Comment: Just use Bayes' Theorem.  What is the probability that he gets the  question right?  What portion of that probability is explained by him having seen the question?

Comment: @lulu There are n options and only one of them is correct so that is why I chose 1/n

Comment: @lulu So is the probability that he gets the question right equal to 1/n?

Comment: It might help to draw a tree diagram. First, either Bob has seen the problem (probability $p$), or he has not (probability $1-p$). Then, either Bob gets it correct or he does not. If he has seen the problem, the probability of correct is $1$, and incorrect is $0$. If he hasn't seen the problem, then the probability of correct is $\frac{1}{n}$, as you say, and the probability of incorrect is $1-\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Don't guess.  Think through the various ways Bob has to get it right and work out he probability of each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ denote the chance that he has seen the question, 
with $q = 1 - p.$

There are two ways that he answers the question correctly:

He has seen the question : chance $= p$.

He has not seen the question, but guesses correctly: chance $= q \times (1/n).$

Therefore, chances that he has seen the question, given that he answered correctly is

$$\frac{p}{p + (q/n)}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I think you already have gotten this far,

$$\Pr[Saw|Correct]  = \frac{\Pr[Correct|Saw]\times\Pr[Saw]}{\Pr[Correct]}$$

We know that $\Pr[Correct|Saw]=1$ and we know that $\Pr[Saw]=p$. The trick is to determine what the probability he is correct. Let's consider this by using the law of total probability,

$$\Pr[Correct]=\Pr[Correct|Saw]\times\Pr[Saw] + \Pr[Correct|Saw^c]\times\Pr[Saw^c]$$

Well we already know the first term is $p$. So now we need to consider the second term. I will leave the computation for you as I think going through it yourself will be a useful exercise.

Here is a hint:
Since he guesses at random we know $\Pr[Correct|Saw^c]$ and since we know that $\Pr[Saw]=p$ we can also find it, how?

Comment: Thank you very much.